# Search engine for Schema.org structured data

Tags: search-engine, rdf, linked-data

Is there a search engine that offers the capability of searching for [Schema.org](https://schema.org/) structured data (e.g., in JSON-LD, Microdata, or RDFa)?

In my case, I am interested in:

1. Finding pages that expose a given Schema.org schema.
2. Querying for specific values of a given Schema.org schema.

A hosted or installable engine would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this dataset based on Common Crawl which would provide the needed answers: http://www.webdatacommons.org/structureddata/2017-12/stats/stats.html. Searching through this dataset to identify Schema.org entries should be a simple matter.

Comment: Update for 2019, released in 2020: http://www.webdatacommons.org/structureddata/2019-12/stats/stats.html